# apply regression tree model to a collection of large rasters?

Tags: raster, r, memory, model

I have used `ctree()` in the R `party` package to generate a regression tree fitting points sampled from a raster of my response variable to values sampled from a collection of rasters of possible driving variables.  I would now like to apply the resulting BinaryTree object to a collection of equivalent rasters to predict a raster surface of the response variable.

Naively, I could make a data frame by extracting values from each of the input rasters using the `raster` functions `values()` or `getValues()` and input the resulting data frame as the `newdata=` parameter in `treeresponse()`, but unless I'm misunderstanding something, wouldn't this allocate memory for all cells in each raster?  How can I do this while taking advantage of the capabilities of the `raster` package (or similar) to read in raster data in blocks?

This question is related but is dealing with generating models rather than applying it, and the solution presented only works for linear models not regression trees: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/72648/how-to-do-regression-analysis-out-of-memory-on-a-set-of-large-rasters-in-r

Comment: Since this question focuses on issues of `R` programming, I would suggest flagging it for migration to [SO] (where a bunch of `R` experts hang out) if you don't get a good answer soon.

Comment: How do I flag it for migration?

Comment: Click on the "flag" link on the left beneath the text of the question.

Comment: Best solution I've been able to come up with is to parse the tree into text (e.g. by modifying the nice code published by Mark Ziem here: <https://heuristically.wordpress.com/2011/10/11/model-decision-tree-in-r-score-in-sas/>), using raster algebra syntax, and then evaluate the expression using eval(parse()).  

This is adequate for ctree and completely unhelpful for more complicated models like cforest().